# What a page and pager mean in SRE context?

Tags: sre

I've been reading the Google SRE Book and I've found the word **page** and **pager** in multiple lines. In this context what do they mean?

[image: sre book image]

[see link](https://sre.google/sre-book/monitoring-distributed-systems/)

Thank you.

Comment: A *pager* is a device for getting a short message to a person who's on-call - might be a text message, might be limited to a phone number that the person needs to call to get more details.  A *page* is a message received by such a device.  They're mostly obsolete these days, since everyone in the world (except for me) has a cell phone now.  I guess the terminology is being reused to refer to the use of a cell phone to get an alert message to an on-call person.